# Why is a struct's field a "non-name"

Tags: go

This code does not work.  It complains that j.Bar is a "non-name":

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "os"

type foo struct {
    Bar string
    Baz int
}

func main() {
    var j foo

    // this next line fails with "non-name j.Bar on left side of :="
    j.Bar, ok := os.LookupEnv("SOME VAR")
    if ( ! ok ) {
        panic("lookup failed!")
    }
    fmt.Printf("j.Bar is now %s\n",j.Bar)
}
```

Now I can change it easily to work:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "os"

type foo struct {
    Bar string
    Baz int
}

func main() {
    var j foo

    val, ok := os.LookupEnv("SOME VAR")
    if ( ! ok ) {
        panic("lookup failed!")
    }
    j.Bar = val
    fmt.Printf("j.Bar is now %s\n",j.Bar)
}
```

I'm really puzzled by the "non-name" error.  j.Bar is a string.  [os.LookupEnv() returns a string](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#LookupEnv) as its first value.  So what is the problem with taking a string and putting it into a string variable?

Comment: See also:
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6842

Answer (score 8):

The `:=` operator simultaneously declares a new variable, and assigns a value to it. `j.Bar` is not a legal variable name in Go; variable names cannot contain periods. Now, obviously you're trying to assign a value to a struct field, not a variable with a period in its name (the compiler just doesn't know it). You can do this, using just assignment without declaration:

```
var ok bool
j.Bar, ok = os.LookupEnv("SOME VAR")
```

Or this, declaring two variables at once:

```
bar,ok := os.LookupEnv("SOME VAR")
if ok {
    j.Bar = bar
}
```

See also: [Go tour on short variable declarations](https://tour.golang.org/basics/10) and [the spec on short variable declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations).

Comment: awesome, perfect explanation :)